# Regression line in ggplot doesn't match computed regression

Tags: r, regression, ggplot2

Im using R and created a chart using ggplot2.

```
ggplot(Month.Data, aes(y=Measure, x=Samples)) +geom_point()  + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

I then create a regression so I can make some predicitions

```
regression <- lm(Samples ~ Measure, data = Month.Data)
```

I pass my data frame of "Measures" to the predict function

predict(regression, Measures)

I'd expect the predictions to be the same as if I used the regression line on the chart, but they aren't the same. Why would this be the case? Is there a setting in ggplot or is my expectation incorrect?

Comment: Aren't you plotting and using lm with `Month.Data` dataset but making predictions using `Measures` dataset ..?

Comment: Yes, Measures is a data frame of 5 "Measure" values. The result of this prediction should be what I would see if i manually used the line on the plot.

Comment: So you estimate your model on different dataset and make predictions on different dataset -- this obviously leads to different results...

Comment: The prediction should be aligned with the regression line on the chart, i'm not saying it should match the actual result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(Month.Data, aes(y=Measure, x=Samples)) + ...
```

Here your y values are `Measure` and your x values `Samples`.

```
regression <- lm(Samples ~ Measure, data = Month.Data)
```

Here your y values are `Samples` and your x values `Measure`.

Those are different models and predictions will be different since OLS minimizes the sum of squared residuals in y direction.

Comment: Yes, this is correct! I should not have made this basic error, thanks for correcting me.